# NSOperation gets completed before background task are over

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

`NSOperation` gets completed before background task are over

I am calling and NSOperation and have set max concurrent task 2
NSOperation calls some background methods
but NSOperation does not wait for the background tasks to be completed 
and get removed from the queue
so next operation starts which I do not want
Please help, how to let NSOperation continue till the background task gets completed.

Comment: Can you show your code where you created the NSOperation object? If you use a subclass, it's crucial that you implemented it *correctly*. If you use the `addOperationWithBlock:` method taking a block as argument, your block must be executing *synchronous*. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you may get your answer here in

1. [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941961/1307844).
2. [StackOverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619786/how-do-i-wait-until-an-nsoperationqueue-has-finished-in-a-unit-test)

Answer (score 1):

NSOperation KVO's it's properties isFinished and isExecuting. From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Upon completion or cancellation of its task, your concurrent operation
> object must generate KVO notifications for both the isExecuting and
> isFinished key paths to mark the final change of state for your
> operation. (In the case of cancellation, it is still important to
> update the isFinished key path, even if the operation did not
> completely finish its task. Queued operations must report that they
> are finished before they can be removed from a queue.) In addition to
> generating KVO notifications, your overrides of the isExecuting and
> isFinished methods should also continue to return accurate values
> based on the state of your operation.

Basically when you generate a notification `isFinished = YES` and `isExecuting = NO`, your NSOperation will be removed from the queue.